# Service for multiple counters

Tags: angularjs

I'm a little stuck on a project (very new with AngularJS). Right now, my HTML is:

```
<button ng-click="decrement()" class="min">-</button>
<input ng-model="counter" type="text" size="1">
<button ng-click="increment()" class="plus">+</button>
```

and my (working) JS:

```
ngToggle.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.image=1;
$scope.decrement=function() {
    if ($scope.counter>1) {$scope.counter--;}       
};
$scope.increment=function() {
    $scope.counter++;
}
}]);
```

This creates a simple counter with + and - buttons. I have now the situation where I want multiple independent counters. In my head, the counting part could easily be handled with a service, so I don't have to repeat myself. But what is the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your question is quite open and there's going to be numerous answers that could help you. I've mocked up a quick example where a service handles the incrementing and decrementing of multiple counters - it may not be suitable for your exact scenario but hopefully it will demonstrate how a service *could* be used.

[http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3763](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3763/)

```
function counterService() {
    var counters = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    return {
        getCounters: getCounters,
        decrement: decrement,
        increment: increment
    };

    function getCounters() {
        return counters;
    }

    function increment(i) {
        if (angular.isDefined(counters[i]))
            counters[i]++;
    }

    function decrement(i) {
        if (angular.isDefined(counters[i]))
            counters[i]--;
    }
}
```

This is the service. All that you need to take away from this is that the state of the counters live in the service and the functions to interact with them are also provided from the service.

Comment: That is indeed what I had in mind! Can you elaborate on your last comment about services?

Also: I feel like I'm missing some crucial point. If I try to copy-paste the jsfiddle code into an html and js file the code doesn't work (Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater)

Comment: It's never a good idea to just copy and paste code that's different from your working environment. As I said, this is just an example, you should try and apply this logic in your application yourself - it's the best way to learn how it all works.